# Check progress of silent Terminal command writing a file?

Tags: perl, terminal

Not really sure if this is possible, but I am running this on Terminal:

`script -q \/my\/directory\/\/$outfile \.\/lexparser.csh $file`

**Explanation**

Through a perl script. The first directory and `$outfile` is where I am saving the output of the Terminal command. the `\.\/lexparser.csh $file` is just calling on that script to work on the input file, `$file`.

**Problem**

However, I put `-q` b/c I didn't want to save the unnecessary print to the file. The file is big ~ 30 thousand lines of text. It has been running for some time now, which was expected.

**Question**

I would like to check and ensure everything is going smoothly. The file output name is in Finder, but I'm afraid if I click on it, it will ruin the output. How can check the progress (possibly the current text file) without disrupting the process?

Thanks for your time, let me know if the question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a new Terminal, navigate to the output directory, and:

```
tail -f <output_file>
```

You will continue to see new appends to the file without interruption to any writing process. Just leave the Terminal open with the `tail` going, and you can watch it all day long. Grab some popcorn.

In addition to [tail](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail), you can also learn about [tee](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee). The point of `tee` is to output to a file while also outputting to `STDOUT` in your terminal. Best of both worlds! Well, someone good aspects of two possible worlds.

Comment: Great! Just  what I was looking for... but my personal, sad news is I still have 28000 sentences to go... and then I have to do it all over again... Popcorn's gonna be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could `tail` the file via the command line which shouldn't cause problems.

Additionally you could have the program print to `stderr` as well as `stdout`, redirect `stdout` to the file and allow `stderr` through so it could tell you it's progress. Though that is more of a 20 / 20 hindsight solution.

Comment: Is there a way to pause the Terminal command, or stop and resume later?